# Create random Word/ Phrase generator using array

Tags: arrays, random

I have a list of over 100 words i want to use, i have looked for a solution to this in several places but as my knowledge of xcode is limited i have no idea how i would implement them, ill give an example of the app i created in java that i want in Xcode (but with a refresh button, i think i know how to do the button though)

```
//import java libraries
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Emotion extends JFrame
{
    //set what you can use
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel phrasem;
    public Emotion()
    {
    setLayout( new FlowLayout());

    //Wordlists
    String[] wordlist =
    {
            "Anger","Misery","Sadness","Happiness","Joy","Fear","Anticipation","Surprise","Shame","Envy","Indignation","Courage","Pride","Love","Confusion","Hope","Respect","Caution","Pain","Rage Melon"
    };

        //number of words the list
        int length = wordlist.length;

        //random number
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * length);


    //building phrase
    String phrase = wordlist[rand];

    // printing phrase
    phrasem = new JLabel("Today your emotion is:");
    add (phrasem);

    label = new JLabel(" " + phrase);
    add (label);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Emotion gui = new Emotion();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setSize(400, 60);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setTitle("My App (Alex Gadd)");

    }

}
```

Comment: This is a language thing and not a IDE thing, try and google how to generate a random number using objective c and how arrays work

Comment: Your asking someone to code this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get a random word from an array

```
NSArray *wordList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Anger",@"Misery",@"Sadness",@"Happiness",@"Joy",@"Fear",@"Anticipation", @"Surprise",@"Shame",@"Envy",@"Indignation",@"Courage",@"Pride",@"Love",@"Confusion",@"Hope",@"Respect",@"Caution",@"Pain",@"Rage Melon", nil];

int randomWord = (int)arc4random() % [wordList count];
NSLog(@"Random word = %@", [wordList objectAtIndex:randomWord]);
```

Comment: ok so i know to use that, but how do i implement that (sorry i really dont have a clue about xcode or c)

Comment: so i can give a little more info i basically want to replace what i have with what you put, this is what i currently have in xcode, this is what i currently have as a practice document;     (IBAction)Random:(id)sender {
        int text = rand() % 1;
        switch (text) {
            case 0:
                textview.text = @"blue";
                break;

Comment: That is somehting you can't expect to be answered on Stack Overflow. There are numerous tutorials for that, here are a couple
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html
http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials